# Possible to oil my Furnace Fan Motor myself and with 3-in-1 Motor Oil?

Tags: heating

My Furnace Fan/Inducer Motor (not the Blower Motor) has been noisy all the time lately. I put some 3-in-1 motor oil by the Gasket. That really seemed to eliminate the noise. Some people have said (outside this forum) to oil it or not oil at all. I chose to oil-the sound was so loud. Was it ok to oil and with that type of oil?

I put it by the gasket. But what are the 2 orange rubber plugs that I can remove off the housing unit? Should oil go in there too?

Don't laugh. I'm a single homeowner and don't know much about furnaces. And I can't afford a HVAC guy right now.

Thanks for the replies. 
(My main question was about whether the 3-in-1 was ok to use to oil the gasket)

Comment: In relation to my answer, I'd also be on the cautious side and turn off the electricity when you do this!

Comment: You might have saved your motor.  For reference, don't use WD-40 or any of the penetrating oils, they will attack and dissolve plastic and rubber parts.

Comment: Almost any kind of oil is helpful in this case if it quieted it down you did the right thing. I would get some heavier oil in there for a long term or longer term fix. Most mothers do need a few drops annually.

Comment: Check online and see if you can find the manual for your furnace. My blower motor has a couple rubber tubes I put 5ml of 10w30 in each year using a plastic syringe. That's what my manual calls for.

Answer (score 1):

3-in-1 will work fine. Since I can't see exactly what your talking about in relation to your '2 orange rubber plugs' most of the time you do remove said plugs and oli until it's full.

Here is actually a video that better explains it in detail: https://youtu.be/UKoK_U_GKZI

Hope this helps!

Comment: That was a good link and should help the OP. A few drops of any motor oil (any weight) will last longer than light oil.+ but 3 in 1 helps to break down the dried up sludge in the bearing as other penetrating oils do.